# Azure logic apps - MySQL connector - insert row action showing auto increment primary key field as required

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm creating a Logic app that uses the SQL connector. When I add an insert row action, the id field is showing as required.

I am wondering what value to put in this field, as it is the primary key and of course set to auto increment in the database.

I'm struggling to see how/why this field is showing as required in Azure.

Is there a way of stopping it being required in Azure, or what value could I add that would work. I've tried NULL, 0, space - and none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

I test the mysql connector and get the same problem as yours.Looks like it's because it's still preview version, the some function are not perfect.

Then I test if i can insert rows with id auto_increment. And I found If you insert id more than 1, first time it will success but then will get error. Then

**I test the 0, even this will get error too however It will insert the value.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

If you want to make it auto-increment , you could only set the id with 0, or you could choose to use sql server, this doesn't need set id(I test).

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

**UPDATE:** You could design the action you want it run after the `Mysql Action` with `Configure run after`. I set it with **has failed** then saved it, then action would run.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Or you could post feedback to the official feedback site.https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback

Comment: Thank you George. You did all the same tests I did :) I would use 0 but I need to hanble the error so the rest of my app runs. Do you know if you can set an action in an app to ignore errors and contine to run the rest of the actions?

Comment: @richyvk  I have updated my answer, you could check it.